# "ERROR: File xxx can't be indexed twice." when analyzing a solution with a mix of C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Below is my Azure pipeline to analyze a solution with a mix of C# and C++.

This is the error of executing the project build command:

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution ERROR: File
> HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/App.config can’t be
> indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce
> disjoint sets for main and test files

How can I resolve this error?

Logs: [build command execute log](https://community.sonarsource.com/uploads/short-url/A7tqnaFqaj8E7qhyPud0nyLgJ6r.txt)

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Dependency
    type: githubenterprise
    endpoint: https://github.azc.ext.xxx.com
    name: cloud-client/Dependency

trigger: none

pool: 'SWindows2022-DEV'

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: Dependency

- script: |
     move Dependency/KHPLib $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://sq.corp.xxxcloud.net/static/cpp/build-wrapper-win-x86.zip' -OutFile 'build-wrapper.zip'
      Expand-Archive -Path 'build-wrapper.zip' -DestinationPath '.'
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases/download/5.13.0.66756/sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.13.0.66756-net46.zip' -OutFile 'sonar-scanner-msbuild.zip'
      Expand-Archive -Path 'sonar-scanner-msbuild.zip' -DestinationPath './SonarScanner'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'KHPLib\src\KHPLib\KHPLib.vcxproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'https://sq.corp.xxxcloud.net'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'manual'
    cliProjectKey: 'xxx_HPCEMConnectionWizardWin'
    cliSources: '.'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output
      sonar.java.file.suffixes=-

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      SonarScanner\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"xxx_HPCEMConnectionWizardWin" /n:"HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.sln" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output="bw-output"
      build-wrapper-win-x86\build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir bw-output "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.sln -t:Rebuild /p:configuration=release /p:platform=x64
      SonarScanner\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end

- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5

- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

- task: sonar-buildbreaker@8
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'https://sq.corp.xxxcloud.net'
```

---

#### Update 2023-05-27

I updated the following pipeline task:

```
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'https://sq.corp.xxxcloud.net'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'manual'
    cliProjectKey: 'xxx_HPCEMConnectionWizardWin'
    cliSources: '.'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output
      sonar.java.file.suffixes=-
      sonar.verbose=true
      sonar.sources=HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/src/,HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/Model/,HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/View/,HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/ViewModel/
```

New error:

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
> 2023-05-27T12:25:22.4759667Z File HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/src/HPCEMConnectionWizardLauncher/framework.h can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

Here is the code I like to analyze:

The C# code (*.cs) directory lists:

- HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/Model/
- HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/View/
- HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/ViewModel/

The C++ code (*.cpp,*.h) directory lists:

- HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/src/

Verbose log: https://community.sonarsource.com/uploads/short-url/pANjC2FqXe3iqumr095tLL1TmLx.txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/App.config` is included twice somehow. You should add `sonar.verbose=true` in the `SonarQubePrepare` step and check what files are indexed by Sonar. Then you can see where the duplication lies. Next, follow [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) to make sure certain files are not indexed twice.

For a quick workaround, just exclude that `HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/App.config` file with:

```
sonar.exclusions= HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/App.config
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @joe-ting-sonar, I've update the SonarQubePrepare settings and uploaded a verbose log for a new error, I don't understand why that .h file is indexed twice? 
Here is my post in SonarQube community 
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-file-xxx-cant-be-indexed-twice-when-analyzing-a-solution-with-a-mix-of-c-and-c/91219/4